# How to replace the value after = using sed command to null

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed

I have scenario where i want to replace the `digit or string` after equal to `=` to null [ blank ]
Without creating new file need to replace in the same file

**Data in file :**

```
name=vilas
age=21
code=1345
```

Need to replace the digit after `code=1345` to `code=`

I have tried this but stuck

```
sed -i 's/^code=$/code=/1g' file.txt
```

Note : The value after code= is going to be dynamic need to use regex pattern match which i am not good with

Comment: `sed -i` creates a new file, so it does not satisfy your requirement.

Comment: In general, actually replacing data in the file is a bad idea.  If you really want to do that,  you can do things like: `sed 's/^code=.*/code=/' file.txt > /tmp/file; cat /tmp/file > file.txt; rm /tmp/file`.  `sed -i` probably satisfies your actual desire but it is creating a new file (and giving it the name that the original file had), and not editing the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var1=456
$ sed -Ei "s/(code=).*/\1$var1/" file
name=vilas
age=21
code=456
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question:

On MacOS and FreeBSD

```
sed -i '' -E 's/^code=[[:digit:]]+$/code=/g' test1.txt
```

On CentOS and Debian

```
sed -i -E 's/^code=[[:digit:]]+$/code=/g' test1.txt
```

You can update the character class to fit your needs.

where

```
-i  Edit files in-place
-E  Interpret regular expressions as extended (modern) regular expressions rather than basic regular expressions (BRE's).
s   The substitute command
g   Apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the first.
```

GNU docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html
SED docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html